# Ubuntu 22.04 NetworkManager is not working

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager

For the last few days my system which only has Ubuntu 22.04 on it is not getting connected to Wifi. It is not showing any Wifi networks no commands show networks are running.
I tried few options, i.e.,

1. `sudo systemctl restart/stop NetworkManager` - The command will keep on running and No results will show in terminal.
2. `sudo nmcli networking off`
3. `sudo nmcli networking on`

None of these commands are working and keep on running on the terminal.
Then I went to see the journal entry. It shows this in the system
[Journal Entry of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4UeP.jpg)

I used the command `journalctl -b -1 -r`

It says **systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Killing process 1256>**

**systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: State 'final-sigterm>**

Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: Please reboot the system *(so there's no traces of your experiments within the uptime)*, then execute `systemctl status wpa_supplicant NetworkManager` and post the output here. And while on it, what does `uname -a` says? Did you try booting older kernel version from the Grub menu, does that fix the problem?